# Yii2 - BInary file downloaded can not be open

Tags: php, yii2

I just create a simple download file function by :

```
  public function actionDownload(){
        $id = Yii::$app->request->getQueryParam('id');
       // $id = Yii::$app->request->post('file_id');
        $path =( new DocumentCRUD())->getDocumentPath($id);
        $response = Yii::$app->response->sendFile($this->ROOT_FOLDER.'/'.$path);
        $response->send();
    }
```

and in view ,file will be downloaded when click link

```
 window.location.href="document/download?id="+file_id
```

The problem is that ,after file downloaded ,I can not open binary file such : image ,exe ... just text file is OK ,and im sure that these file on server is no problem

What I have to do ?

Comment: Have you set the HTTP header "Content-Type" properly? If not the receiver will probably use "text/html" as default.

Comment: Thanks ,I found my problem,just clear all dummy output before send file by ob_end() ,

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem,just clear all dummy output before send file by ob_end()